# Refreshing your question

Tags: support, questions

Is there a way to make your question pop back up in the front/top again, so that more people see it? I get upset because if your question is not answered in the first second it will never get answered.

Comment: "if your question is not answered in the first second it will never get answered" _[citation needed]_

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6680/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main way to do this is to offer a bounty. You will need to earn some more rep before you are able to do this.

The question will also pop back to the top if you edit it. But you should not do that unless the edit will substantially improve the question, e.g. by adding more information or making it clearer.